# How can I properly parse for a tagged user in my Discord bot?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am adding profile cards onto my Discord bot, but I've come across one issue. When someone types `!profile @user` I am not sure how to properly parse for @user so the bot knows which profile card to lookup.

I first parse message.content and then remove the 9 first chars of the message content (which is always `!profile`) but the rest of the message content returns the user_id which looks `<@289583108183948460>` instead of the user's discrim. I have tried using re.sub to remove the special characters (@, >, and <) like this:

```
a = str(message.content[9:])
removeSpecialChars = re.sub("[!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+]", " ", a)
print(removeSpecialChars)
```

But the weird characters are still there when I only want the number so I can search it in the database easily. I'm sure there's a way better way to do this though but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

discord.py's message objects include a `Message.mentions` attribute so you can iterate over a list of `Member`. Here are the doc listings for [async](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) and [rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.mentions).

With this you can simply iterate over the mentions as so:

```
for member in ctx.message.mentions:
    # do stuff with member
```

## what you actually want

discord.py allows you to grab `discord.Member` objects from messages with [type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). simply add the following to the command

```
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = member or ctx.message.author
```