# How to get the ID of a mentioned User in Python discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I was programming a discord bot in python. But there is a problem. I know how to mention the user who sent the message. But how do I get the ID of a user that is mentioned by the author in the message? I couldn't get the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the user(s) that were mentioned in a message using `message.mentions` ([async](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) [rewrite](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.mentions))

From there, you can either get the ID from the Member object, or get a formatted mention from those objects

```
message.mentions[0].id
message.mentions[0].mention
```

Comment: So will the following example be correct?
`async def on_message():
    if message.content.upper() == "+CALL":
         await bot.send_message(message.channel, "<%s> and <%s> are 
              called to come" % (message.mentions[0].id,message.mentions[1].id))`

Comment: No. Mentions are in the format `<@...>` not just `<...>`. Besides, you can just use `member.mention` to create a preformatted mention. `"%s" % message.mentions[0].mention`. Lastly, it might be worth looking into [`str.format`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 0):

`discord.Message` objects have an attribute of `mentions` that returns a list of `discord.Member` objects of all users mentioned in the message content, `discord.Member` objects have `discord.User` objects as parents so you can access `discord.User` attributes like `author.id` and `author.name` etc. simply iterate over the mentions with

```
for member in message.mentions:
    # do stuff with member
```

You should really be using `discord.ext.commands`(async rewrite)
because making a command parser that purely works in `on_message` event method is a bad non pythonic idea.

### What you probably want

seems like all you just want is to be able to access the author object of the message and the users mentioned in the message as parameters, for that please consult my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174271/how-can-i-properly-parse-for-a-tagged-user-in-my-discord-bot/48174605#48174605). To access the author you can simply do it through the `discord.Message` object with `message.author`