# How to make my discord.py bot respond to a specific user being mentioned?

Tags: discord.py

I'd like my bot to respond when a certain user is mentioned. I've only found snippets of the answer on Google and I can't quite put them together. I've noticed that if I call a string in place of user ID it works, but if I call the string with the user ID in the same message it returns nothing.

Any insight is appreciated, work is below (subbing the desired users id into <@user_id> of course):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
        #Making sure it doesn't respond to itself

    if "@here" in message.content: 
      return
    if "@everyone" in message.content:
      return
        #Making sure it doesn't respond to tags including everyone

    if '<@user_id>' in message.content:
        clock = get_time()
        clock = json.dumps(clock, indent=4)
        await message.channel.send("The time in Athens is currently: ")
        await message.channel.send(clock[-11: -6])

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the ID of a mentioned User in Python discord bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354901/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-mentioned-user-in-python-discord-bot)

Answer (score 0):

Message object have a mentions object, so you can get the mentioned user from there like this:

```py
    message.mentions[0]
```

That returns the user object, you can do whatever you want with that.

If you want to check if there is a mention in the message just do:

```py
    if message.mentions:
        #your code
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! That got me one step closer (unless I'm missing something), but running it gave me this error:

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 31, in on_message
    if user_id in message.mentions[0]:
TypeError: argument of type 'Member' is not iterable

I have no idea how to proceed to make Member iterable. Code is in the comment below:

Comment: ` python  
        if user_id in message.mentions[0]:  
            clock = get_time()  
            clock = json.dumps(clock, indent=4)  
            await message.channel.send("The time in Athens is currently: ")  
            await message.channel.send(clock[-11: -6])`